# How to make a sum of number fields to single field in contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: plugins, wordpress, contact-form-7

below is the code of table in contact form 7,

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>RX #</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX1 placeholder "RX1"]</td>
<td>[number RX1Amount placeholder "RX1 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX2 placeholder "RX2"]</td>
<td>[number RX2Amount placeholder "RX2 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX3 placeholder "RX3"]</td>
<td>[number RX3Amount placeholder "RX3 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX4 placeholder "RX4"]</td>
<td>[number RX4Amount placeholder "RX4 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX5 placeholder "RX5"]</td>
<td>[number RX5Amount placeholder "RX5 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount</td>
<td>[number TotalAmount]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want sum the amount column in such a way that when i enter number/amount in any of the field it should be updated in last total row, if i enter number/amount in more than one row, sum of all rows should be updated in last total row.

for clear understanding view the below image.

[image: requriement]

can any one help me out?

Comment: The `TotalAmount` should be updated when user changes *any* other `input[type="number"]`? This value should be the sum of all the other 10 fields or just the 5 "amount" ones?

Comment: only the 5 amounts, the fields of second column should get sum. sum of that 5 amount fields should be updated in the last field.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test this code, but if it doesn't run at least it will help you to figure out the solution. I've added a class to amount fields, an id to the total and a function to the input field, triggered every time the field have it's value changed:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>RX #</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX1 placeholder "RX1"]</td>
<td>[number RX1Amount class:amount-field placeholder "RX1 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX2 placeholder "RX2"]</td>
<td>[number RX2Amount class:amount-field placeholder "RX2 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX3 placeholder "RX3"]</td>
<td>[number RX3Amount class:amount-field placeholder "RX3 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX4 placeholder "RX4"]</td>
<td>[number RX4Amount class:amount-field placeholder "RX4 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>[number RX5 placeholder "RX5"]</td>
<td>[number RX5Amount class:amount-field placeholder "RX5 Amount"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount</td>
<td>[number TotalAmount id:total-amount]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The Js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $amount_fields = $('.amount-field'),
        $total_amount = $('#total-amount');

    $amount_fields.on('input', function(e) {
        var final_value = 0;
        $amount_fields.each(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) final_value += parseInt(value);
        });
        $total_amount.val(final_value);
    })
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this

Comment: Hello Felipe Elia, Thanks once again the code is working, but the output is not correct, instead of getting added the amounts they are getting concatinated, if i kept the values such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, the output should me sum of all the values which is 15, but i am getting 012345 as a output. please help me out.

Comment: try using `final_value += parseInt(value);`. If it works I'll update my answer.